# Is this a bad way to handle a String DateTime Constraint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I created my own custom annotation. It basically tries to parse a String into LocalDateTime while following a custom pattern.

Here is the annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidateDateStringImpl.class)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidateDateString {
    String message() default "Invalid date-time format";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Here is the Validation Logic:

```
@Slf4j
public class ValidateDateStringImpl implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateDateString, String> {

    private  DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidateDateString constraintAnnotation) {
        dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String dateString, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        try{
            LocalDateTime.parse(dateString,dateTimeFormatter);
        }
        catch (DateTimeParseException ex){
            log.info(String.valueOf(ex));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is where the annotation is being used:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Foo{

    @NotBlank
    @ValidateDateString
    private String fooDateTime;

}
```

Is this a good approach, or are there some better alternatives. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would work (some minor improvements like picking a right overload of log.info to pass exception, or reading time format from the annotation) but consider using `java.time` classes in your model, and pushing date formatting to the presentation layer.

Comment: If your input includes a `Z`, offset, or time zone on the end, you should be parsing as an `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`, respectively, *not* a `LocalDateTime`.